# How two untrusted parties can make transactions without any involvement of the third-party?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design

I'm trying to create a contract where where `PartyA` and `PartyB` had to trade. `PartyA` sends money to a contract and `PartyB` sends goods to `partyA`. After `partyA` receives the goods it allows `PartyB` to retrieve it's money from the contract.
In any case possible a third party is needed. I'm I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your biggest problem is that a contract can only receive assets which are inside the blockchain. You can't send regular money ($, €, any fiat) in blockchain and you can't send goods in blockchain.

What you'd basically need is some way for an external party to tell the contract about the state of the assets (money and goods) outside blockchain. But it's really difficult to do this in a trustless way as you have to trust some entity which inputs the data to the blockchain.

So, yes, most likely a third party is needed.

Answer (score 3):

It could be the Oracle that traces the delivery - many DHL-type delivery networks provide APIs to their information systems. Although there are certain subtleties with determining the identifier of the tracked "package".

Comment: yeap in anyway. 3rd party is needed.

Comment: A particular concern would be the "Oops, Wrong Package" scam where one sends a product of little value in order to make it look like the right product has been delivered.